# Removing Keys In Associative Array Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to retain only certain keys, and remove the rest from an external API. I have an array (http://pastebin.com/vU8T4y7h), "data" containing the objects:

```
foreach ($data as $media) {
    foreach (array_keys($media) as $media_key) {
        if ($media_key!=="created_time" && $media_key!=="likes" && $media_key!=="images" && $media_key!=="id") {
            unset($media[$media_key]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I am trying to only keep the `created_time`, `likes`, `images`, and `id` keys, however, the above code isn't working. Any ideas as to why? Any other elegant solutions to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because you aren't unsetting from the original `$data` object.  You can fix it one of two ways.  Either access by reference or update your `unset` to act on the original `$data` object instead.

Using reference:

```
foreach($data as &$media) {
```

Unsetting from `$data`

```
unset($data[$media][$media_key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach creates a **copy** of each array element, so unsetting $media[$media_key] only unsets from the copy; and you want to unset from the original $data array:

```
foreach ($data as $mediaRef => $media) {
    foreach (array_keys($media) as $media_key) {
        if ($media_key!=="created_time" && $media_key!=="likes" && $media_key!=="images" && $media_key!=="id") {
            unset($data[$mediaRef][$media_key]);
        }
    }
}
```

or (by reference)

```
foreach ($data as &$media) {
    foreach (array_keys($media) as $media_key) {
        if ($media_key!=="created_time" && $media_key!=="likes" && $media_key!=="images" && $media_key!=="id") {
            unset($media[$media_key]);
        }
    }
}
unset($media);
```

Comment: Good catch on needing foreach k, v instead of just value in first iteration when deleting from original data source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to do that kind of thing easily:

```
$keepTheseKeys = array_flip(array('created_time', 'likes', 'images', 'id'));

foreach ($data as &$media) {
    $media = array_intersect_key($media, $keepTheseKeys);
}
unset($media);
```

## The error

The error in the code in the question is that you're updating a temporary variable, either pass media by reference (see above example) - or refer to the original variable:

```
foreach ($data as $i => $media) {
    $data[$i] = ...
```

Comment: I think you want `array_intersect_key` instead of `array_diff_key`.

Comment: indeed I do @NullUserException

Comment: You want `unset($media)` after the loop as well.

Comment: @Sven that's only important if you're reusing references which is a terrible idea.

Comment: I'd say using references in foreach would be a terrible thing in the first place, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for an elegant solution:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $media) {
    foreach (array_keys($media) as $media_key) {
        if (!in_array($media_key, array("created_time", "likes", "images", "id"))) {
            unset($data[$key][$media_key]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd try to avoid using references in foreach loops because you need to unset the referenced variable. If not, hard to detect errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use

```
foreach (array_keys($media) as $media_key) {
```

you can use

```
foreach($media as $media_key => $media_value){
```

instead

But for your question, in the first line, you are going through $data, and in each cycle, the current value in $data is assigned into $media. But media doesn't have any connection back to original $data, so it is discarded on next iteration, when new value is assigned from $data to $media.

You have two options:

1. Use references:

   ```
   foreach($data as &$media) { // and so on... this should work, but i don't suggest it
   ```
2. in first line, write

   ```
   foreach($data as $media_k => $media) {
   ```

   and in fourth line, write

   ```
   unset($data[$media_k][$media_key]); //
   ```